# suma de columnas mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

[image: tabla similar]

Hola que tal! necesito de su ayuda, estoy haciendo esto, pero la respuesta es muy dificil de encontrar en internet, llevo horas buscando mal la solucion a mi respuesta, lamento si es algo básica mi pregunta,

PROBLEMA:
Necesito Sumar todas las ventas de ejemplo: robert que en total serían 130 en la fila 0 170 en la fila 3 y 140 en la fila 4

Estoy llamando los datos con mysql filtrando solo las ventas de robert para sumarlas en su totalidad, mi tabla tiene mas columnas.
Estaba intentando con while pero solo me repite los datos y suma de variables tampoco me funcionaba.

NECESITO:
La suma total de las ventas de robert.

Sé que para la mayoría será muy facil mi pregunta, estoy aprendiendo :) gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Podrías poner por favor cómo están formadas tus tablas y cómo se relacionan? ¿Es una sola tabla, son varias tablas?... Por ejemplo, ¿cómo se llama la columna que guarda las ventas? ¿Tiene `robert`
 alguna columna `id` que lo identifique de forma única?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconozco la estructura completa de su tabla, pero según lo que le entendí a lo que desea hacer. La consulta para sumar el total de las ventas que realizó Robert es la siguiente.

Nota. Puede ser una posible solución a lo que necesita, pues como lo mencioné al inicio desconozco la estructura de las tablas.

```js
SELECT sum(venta1+venta2+venta3) from prueba where vendedor='robert'
```

La sentencia lo que hace es sumar todos los valores de la columna ventas1 más la columna ventas2 y la columna ventas3 donde el vendedor es Robert.

Comment: En vez de dar una solución basada en un **posible diseño erróneo,** yo preguntaría por qué `Robert` tiene que tener diferentes columnas para sus ventas... ¿y cuando `Robert` tenga 1,000 ventas o un millón de ventas?

Comment: tiene mas restricciones y no puede llegar a 1 millon por la capacidad humana de vender, semanalmente esta suma renovará :) gracias por tu observacion, podría haber servido

Comment: Se dice que este diseño puede ser erróneo porque estaría en contra de una regla conocida como "Primera Forma Normal (1FN)" (ver más en [Normalización de Bases de Datos (wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)). En este caso se resolvería añadiendo una tabla `ventas` (con columnas: `id_vendedor` y `valor`): así, se podría consultar cada venta como una fila separada ya que estarían asociadas al id del vendedor, y podría haber infinita cantidad de ventas sin alterar constantemente la estructura de la tabla `vendedores`.